# going over entire the list and check whether items exists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The database in my Prolog file looks like this ->

```
stage('crepe',2,'Stir the items into a consistent dough.',[],['pot','blender']).
```

I want to use the following query and get this result ->

```
?- equipmentStage(‘crepe’, ‘blender’, Y).
Y = [‘Stir the items into a consistent dough.’] .
```

I tried using the following code, but when I try the query it gives back an empty list. So Prolog concludes no such thing exists. Whereas when I try the query with the first element of the list, 'pot', in the database it gives back the correct output. ->

```
equipmentStage(Food,Equipment,StageTxt):-
findall(Txt, stage(Food, _, Txt, _, [Equipment]),StageTxt).
```

So my question is how do I also get the correct result with the second item in the list? I'm new to Prolog and the help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my two main rules for using `findall` (and similar predicates like `setof` or `bagof`):

1. Don't use `findall`. You probably don't need a list of results. Backtracking over results is usually what you want instead. Define a predicate that enumerates your solutions by backtracking.
2. If you really really want a list (you probably don't), proceed as follows: Take your predicate definition from step 1. Apply `findall` to that; never put a complex query into `findall`.

So for your problem, step 1:

```
food_equipment_stage(Food, Equipment, Stage) :-
    stage(Food, _, Stage, _, Equipments),
    member(Equipment, Equipments).
```

This gives a single answer:

```
?- food_equipment_stage(crepe, blender, Stage).
Stage = 'Stir the items into a consistent dough.'.
```

With a bigger knowledge base, this would enumerate answers one by one.

Are you absolutely sure that you need a list, which you very probably don't? If yes (but probably no), in step 2 it is easy to apply `findall` to the definition from step 1 (but you probably don't even want to):

```
food_equipment_stages(Food, Equipment, Stages) :-
    findall(Stage, food_equipment_stage(Food, Equipment, Stage), Stages).
```

This gives you a list:

```
?- food_equipment_stages(crepe, blender, Stages).
Stages = ['Stir the items into a consistent dough.'].
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! Unfortunately it has to be in a list. But I do wonder how you could get the output to look like this ->  [[pot, ‘Stir the items into a consistent dough.’ ], [blender, ‘Stir the items into a consistent dough.’ ]]. Could you help me with this too?

Comment: `findall([Equipment, Stage], food_equipment_stage(Food, Equipment, Stage), EquipmentsAndStages)`

Comment: What about `setof/3`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `findall` matches only when there is one `Equipment`. You should just check if your equipment is in the list of equipments(`Es`) of recipe.

```
equipmentStage(Food,Equipment,StageTxt):-
    findall(Txt, (stage(Food, _, Txt, _, Es), member(Equipment, Es)),StageTxt).
```

If you want equipment listed with description :

```
equipment_desc(Food,[Equipment, StageTxt]):-
    stage(Food, _, StageTxt, _, Es),
    member(Equipment, Es).
```

```
?- equipmentStage('crepe', Ls).
Ls = [pot, 'Stir the items into a consistent dough.'] ;
Ls = [blender, 'Stir the items into a consistent dough.'].
```

If you want them as list instead of multiple solutions then you can just grab all the equipment and create the list using `maplist` as follows :

```
pair_rev(H, T, [T, H]).
equipment_desc_list(Food, Ls):-
    stage(Food, _, StageTxt, _, Es),
    maplist(pair_rev(StageTxt), Es, Ls).
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I have another question, say I would like to return both of the equipments, so like this -> [[pot, ‘Stir the items into a consistent dough.’ ], [blender, ‘Stir the items into a consistent dough.’ ]]. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use member, the thing is findall checks and compares with the values it has. In your fact you have ['pot','blender'], if you try to give only 'blender', findall will reject it and you will be returned with an empty list []. So what you can do is use member to compare your 'blender', that checks it if it exists in ['pot','blender'] then it can easily execute.

```
stage('crepe',2,'Stir the items into a consistent dough.',[],['pot','blender']).

t(A,B,S):-
    stage(_,_,_,_,W),
    member(B,W),
    findall(C,stage(A,_,C,_,W),S).

?-t('crepe','blender',S).
S = ['Stir the items into a consistent dough.']
```